# Get all versions of a Nexus repository via REST api

Tags: nexus

I want to list all available versions of a Nexus (2.11.1-01) snapshot repository.
The way via REST api / lucene and `gav coordinates` like that :

```
http://nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.foo&a=foo-bar&v=
```

lists the snapshot versions, **but also** release versions, because the artifact foo-bar also exists in a release repository. Because of that, i read the maven-metadata.xml :

```
http://nexus/service/local/repositories/com-foo-snapshots/content/com/foo/foo-bar/maven-metadata.xml
```

The lucene search lacks a repository coordinate like the maven feature, f.e.
get the latest version of a snapshot :

```
http://nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=com-foo-snapshots&g=com.foo&a=foo-bar&v=0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

or get the recent snapshot version :

```
http://nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=com-foo-snapshots&g=com.foo&a=foo-bar&v=LATEST
```

Seems, i cant't use the maven-metadata.xml, because not every repository contains that file.
Is there any other way via Nexus REST api or another api to get all versions of a specific Nexus repository/artifactid even if artefactid exists in different repositories ?
Is it possible to force the creation of a maven-metadata.xml for every repository ?
The available administrative scheduled Nexus Task ain't sufficient, maybe a trigger that fires with every artifact update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to manually parse maven-metadata.xml.

```
http://nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=com.foo&a=foo-bar
```

returns for every `<artifactHit>` all the remaining items that uniquely identify whatever can be downloaded from Nexus, that is: `<repositoryId>` and `<extension>` (and `<classifier>` here undefined):

```
...
<artifact>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
  <latestSnapshot>2.8.5-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
  <latestSnapshotRepositoryId>snapshots</latestSnapshotRepositoryId>
  <latestRelease>2.8.3</latestRelease>
  <latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
  <artifactHits>
    <artifactHit>
      <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
      <artifactLinks>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>pom</extension>
        </artifactLink>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>war</extension>
        </artifactLink>
      </artifactLinks>
    </artifactHit>
  </artifactHits>
</artifact>
<artifact>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-bar</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
  <latestSnapshot>2.8.5-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
  <latestSnapshotRepositoryId>snapshots</latestSnapshotRepositoryId>
  <latestRelease>2.8.3</latestRelease>
  <latestReleaseRepositoryId>releases</latestReleaseRepositoryId>
  <artifactHits>
    <artifactHit>
      <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
      <artifactLinks>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>pom</extension>
        </artifactLink>
        <artifactLink>
          <extension>war</extension>
        </artifactLink>
      </artifactLinks>
    </artifactHit>
  </artifactHits>
</artifact>
```

So after you parse lucene/search response on your own, you can filter it by repositoryId. I think it answers how "to get all versions of a specific Nexus repository/artifactid even if artefactid exists in different repositories".